# How to insert 3 image to 3 field in DB Laravel

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, laravel

I want to insert 3 images to 3 fields in DB, but I can't move this to folder public.
My code in function store in Controller

```
   $room =  Room::create([
        'img1' =>  $request->img1 ,
        'img2' =>$request->img2,
        'img3' =>$request->img3,
        ...
    ]);
    $room->save();
    if ($request->hasFile('img1')) {
        $request->img1->move(public_path('images/rooms'), $request->img1);
    } 
    if ($request->hasFile('img2')) {
        $request->img2->move(public_path('images/rooms'), $request->img2);
    }
    if ($request->hasFile('img3')) {
        $request->img3->move(public_path('images/rooms'), $request->img3);
    }
```

Someone help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

if ($request->hasFile('img1') {
  Storage::put('images/rooms', $request->img1);
}
```

Comment: not working bro, on DB just save is name file but can't move to folder public/images/rooms, so that can't show to view

Comment: Have you tried with FileStorage with PUT? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#obtaining-disk-instances

Comment: Not working bro, created, on DB save name file but can't move to folder :(

Comment: Have you check with your folder and see the image which's you uploaded?

Comment: Folder is empty bro.

Comment: I checked, this created and save name file to DB, only issue is can't move to folder :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure this method is working perfectly. you might not set permission to store your file at your local. Debug your code by checking with log file. Good luck!